# Is there a way to enable Chrome Flags in Flutter WebView?

Tags: flutter, uiwebview, android-webview

I am working on a Flutter App, where I need to enable **WebVR** in Flutter WebView. In the Google Chrome browser, it can be used by enabling **webvr** by going to this link: chrome://flags/#enable-webvr. 
So, is there a way to enable **Chrome Flags** in **Flutter WebView**?